# Is $\mathbb{Q}^n$ a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Is $\mathbb{Q}^n$ a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$ or over $\mathbb{Q}$?

$\mathbb{Q}^n$ is clearly not a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, because scalar multiplication of some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ by $\pi$ renders $\pi q$, which is irrational.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to be a vector space over $\mathbb Z$, because $\mathbb Z$ is not a field. However, it is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't have a vector space over $\Bbb Z$. By definition, a vector space is required to be over a field. If you take away the field requirement, what you're left with is calles a *module*. And yes, $\Bbb Q^n$ is definitely a $\Bbb Z$-module.

That being said, there is a list of $10$ requirements (or thereabouts, it varies slightly) for a space like $\Bbb Q^n$ to be a vector space over a field like $\Bbb Q$. All of them should be easily verifiable. So yes, $\Bbb Q^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Note that nothing here is said about the _operations_ on the vector spaces. Technically that's bad form. A vector space isn't just a set and a base field, it's a set and a base field together with two operations. However, in the case of $\Bbb Z, \Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q^n$, there are standard operations, and unless otherwise specified, you can be pretty certain that that's what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}^n$ can't be a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a field.

To see that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ you could first prove that every field $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space over itself and then since the product of vector spaces is a vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and so $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z$ is a ring but not a field.  See *modules over rings* for a generalization of vector spaces over fields.

$\Bbb Q$ would be a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$. $\Bbb Q^n$ an $n$-dimensional one.